# How to create a MqttClient in vert.x and reused in other class or compent?

Tags: java, mqtt, vert.x

Fisrt, I want to make a MqttClient and reuse in other class, this is how I want to do

```
public class MqttClientUtil {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MqttClientUtil.class);
private static final String BROKER_HOST = "localhost";
private static final int BROKER_PORT = 1883;
private static MqttClient mqttClient;

public static MqttClient getMqttClientUtil() {
    if (null == mqttClient) {
        mqttClient = MqttClient.create(Vertx.vertx())
            .connect(BROKER_PORT, BROKER_HOST, res -> {
                System.out.println(res);
            });
        return mqttClient;
    } else {
        return mqttClient;
    }
}
```

}

In this code, I don't process two or more thread simultaneously get the client.But it does not work, it seems the thread is blocked in connect function.

What is the right way to do？

Comment: The connect function is async,so need to wait or wait notify

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you could block the method until it gets connected using a `CountDownLatch`:

```
public class MqttClientUtil {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MqttClientUtil.class);
    private static final String BROKER_HOST = "iot.eclipse.org";
    private static final int BROKER_PORT = 1883;
    private static MqttClient mqttClient;

    public static MqttClient getMqttClientUtil() {
        if (mqttClient == null) {
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            mqttClient = MqttClient.create(Vertx.vertx()).connect(BROKER_PORT, BROKER_HOST, res -> {
                if (res.succeeded()) System.out.println("connected");
                latch.countDown();
            });

            try { latch.await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        return mqttClient;
    }
}
```